# Can put a bulma columns inside a level-item?

Tags: css, bulma

I am trying to put a columns inside a level-item, but it seems to shrink to a small width. Is there a way to make the columns occupy the full width of the level-item?

Below is the code:

```
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.3/css/bulma.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="level">
    <div class="level-item">
      <div class="columns">
        <div class="column is-1">
          hi
        </div>
        <div class="column is-2">
          hi2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add helper class `is-flex-grow-1` to `columns`

```
     <div class="level">
        <div class="level-item">
          <div class="columns is-flex-grow-1">
            <div class="column">
              hi
            </div>
            <div class="column">
              hi2
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```